# Compile method squeak

Tags: methods, smalltalk, squeak

I was searching the web for compile method declaration and didn't find any,
I didn't find it on the web either in the squeak application browser,
Can anyone explain how does it work? what does it take? For now, I know that it takes a string but I don't know how the string supposed to be, and what it supposed to be built from (what should it include inside it)

Any explanations?

Comment: Your question seems to indicate that you are looking for the Smalltalk syntax, which can be learned online from several sources.

Comment: Leandro is right.  Here at SO we try to help you with specific questions - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  You should read a good source like Squeak by Example - https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/313.  Return to us with a specific issue you are having.